# Where can I sell Albanian currency

Tags: money

I found a small amount of Albanian lekë from summer's visit there. Is there any place in Ireland / UK where I can change those back into EUR, GBP or Dollars??

Comment: Did you try your bank, and any local currency exchange bureaus?

Comment: Any local currency exchange should do... Maybe post office or Debenhams...